# get file path in joomla from any other directory

Tags: php, joomla

i am working on joomla modules but facing some problems. i create more than 7 modules and every one had its on dbcon.php file which contain connection with db code. now the problem is that let us suppose i change the password so now i have to change password in every dbcon.php file in every module which is not the correct way. what i want to do is to place a general dbcon.php file for every module and include that file in every module so when ever i need to change the credentials so i have to chage dbcon.php file once for each and every custom module.

so for that purpose i put dbcon.php file inside modules folder and then try to get that file like that

```
  include( JURI::base().'modules/dbcon.php');
```

which return me that path

```
  http://localhost/Jmd_tests/modules/dbcon.php
```

which is correct but it gives me warnings and module is not working.

here are the warning messages

```
 Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\Jmd_tests\modules\mod_stune_cat_indians\helper.php on line 74

 Warning: include(http://localhost/Jmd_tests/modules/dbcon.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\wamp\www\Jmd_tests\modules\mod_stune_cat_indians\helper.php on line 74

 Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'http://localhost/Jmd_tests/modules/dbcon.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\Jmd_tests\modules\mod_stune_cat_indians\helper.php on line 74
```

so now i am stuck over here and dont know what to do to get correct results. i will greatly appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why you need db file in your module ?

use joomla default Db object instead of file include.

like below.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('your mysql query');
$db->query();
$res = $db->loadAssocList();//for multiple rows only single row use $db->loadAssoc();

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($res);
```

this should be a function in your module helper.

For getting correct path use.
`JURI::root()` will return http://yourdomain.com/

`JPATH_SITE` will return upto /public_html in your case this is required.

hope its solve your problem.